# variable of function within a function is not being recognized

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So i have this function that works great at adding up the sum of all values of a specific field in an array, in this case num_sold

So the array is something like this

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num_sold"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num_sold"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num_sold"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["num_sold"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
}

// this correctly returns 21
$total = array_sum(array_map(
        function($element){
            return $element['num_sold'];
        },
        $array));
```

Now i want to be able to reuse this function on other field names so i wanted to create a function however the $field value isn't getting through. In php storm it says the $field value in sumFieldArray($field,$array) is not used anywhere but its clearly in the function.

I'm guessing it might be a scope issue so i tried doing global $field on the first line but that made no difference and instead it now says the global $field is not used anywhere. What am i doing wrong.

```
public static function sumFieldArray($field,$array)
    {
        $field_sum = array_sum(array_map(
            function($element, $field){
                return $element[$field];
            },
            $array));
        return $field_sum;
    }
```

Comment: php has exactly two scopes: global (top-level of your code), and local - within the current block. a variable defined at some intermediate level is essentially totally inaccessible, since global goes ONLY to the absolute top-level scope. there's no `parent $var` or `grandparent $var` scoping ability.

Comment: @MarcB You're forgetting the `use()` option in function expressions.

Comment: @barmar: ah yeah, true enough. but that's something that has to be done in the parent scope. a child can't reach back and fetch that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this is a scope issue. You have to inherit parent scope with *use*.

```
public static function sumFieldArray($field, $array)
{
    $field_sum = array_sum(array_map(
        function($element, $field) use ($field) {
            return $element[$field];
        },
        $array));
    return $field_sum;
}
```

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2):

`array_sum()` calls the function with only one argument, the array element. It won't pass `$field` as the second argument. You can use the `use()` option to allow the inner function to access a variable in the outside scope.

```
public static function sumFieldArray($field,$array)
    {
        $field_sum = array_sum(array_map(
            function ($element) use($field) {
                return $element[$field];
            },
            $array));
        return $field_sum;
    }
```

If you're using PHP 5.5+, you can also use the [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to extract all the values of that field.

```
public static function sumFieldArray($field,$array)
    {
        return array_sum(array_column($array, $field));
    }
```

Comment: This would have been my preferred answer since it gives that useful array_column version even though that didn't work for me as i dont have php 5.5 others will find it useful however that code isnt valid. In php storm it says it expects ( after function so doing "function use($field) ($element){" will not work. I imagine it just needs a quick tweak and it will be a useful answer, appreciate the help.

Comment: I had the `use` option in the wrong place, it goes after the argument list.